# Click event doesn't work on when dynamically adding classes to controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, dynamic, webforms

I have the following components:

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="testjavascript" Enabled="false" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
<asp:button runat="server" ID="testcodebehind" OnClick="testfunction" />
```

I have this javascript class function:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    alert("it works!");
    return false;
});
```

I have the buttons inside an update panel and it is working asynchronously. When clicked, **testcodebehind** enables and adds the class "close" to the **testjavascript** button:

```
testjavascript.Enabled = true;
testjavascript.Attributes.Add("class", "close");
```

Now here is my problem, when I click on **`testcodebehind`**, it works and **`testjavascript`** becomes enabled. **`testjavasctipt`** also gets the class "close" (F12 - inspect), but clicking on it does not trigger the javascript function! I know that the function works because if I change the **`testjavascript`** button and manually add the class close to it, then it works.

I checked online (for hours) and found several links, one of them was this:
[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Many of the other links were basically the same. But I already have .on!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have `on()`, but have you actually read any of the answers, or the documentation, on how to use `on()` with dynamically generated elements, as that's not at all what you're doing? It's something similar to `$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: Forgot to mention that, I did that as well, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [delegate the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
    alert("it works!");
    return false;
});
```

The reason is, when the document is loaded, you bind the events to the elements those exist. But when you add elements dynamically, through AJAX or JavaScript, they are not present when the event was bound at first.

So this delegation will listen for any DOM Change happening within the static parent and once something happens, it immediately fires the event binding script again to all those.

I saw that you already saw the other links, but didn't know how to implement it, so I have added the code for you to just copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry Praveen, I forgot to mention that, I did that as well and got the same result, I am completely baffled as to why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Also check if class `.close` is added to the button.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    console.log("it works");
    return false;
});
```

You can also do it this way for controls in `UpdatePanel` because they are not loaded each time.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        console.log("Now this should work");
        return false;
    });
});
```